# Question about local Git repository and finding the URL of a local Git repository from where it was originally cloned

Tags: git, github

I pulled a project with several forks on GitHub, but forgot which fork it was. How do I determine which fork I pulled?

Comment: `git remote -v` will show you the remotes, the one you cloned from is `origin` by default but you could have changed that.

Comment: Or look into `.git/config` file (but `git remote -vv` is more user-friendly)